# Get selected value from li in jquery

Tags: jquery, this

Using jquery to find out the value on a clicked event. Each time the `delete` class is clicked the `hidden`variable returns the first `hdid` instead of the clicked `hdid`. When I use the `this` it returns the entire `delete` class but I only need the 'hdid' of the select class. The question is how can I use `this` to set the variable to the selected `hdid`

```
<form id="frmDelete" method="post" action="delete-class.php">
            <ul id="class">
                <li>
                    <div class="delete">ED 123-123<input type="hidden" name="hdid" id="hdid" value="6"/></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="delete">EDU 121-101<input type="hidden" name="hdid" id="hdid" value="7"/></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="delete">STU 120-456<input type="hidden" name="hdid" id="hdid" value="8"/></div>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".delete").click(function() {
                var hidden = $('#hdid').val();
                console.log(hidden);
                console.log(this);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `id="hdid"` should be unique to the element, else use `class="hdid ..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function() {
            var hidden = $(this).find("hidden").val();
            console.log(hidden);
        });
    });
```

And id should be unique

Comment: It is undefined when I run this but if I use the same id for all it works.

Comment: I just used a `class` instead of `id` and changed the ` var hidden = $(this).find('.hdid').val();` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function() {
        var $div = $(this);
        console.log($div.children("input").prop("name"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the ID hdid on the same page. it is not a good idea to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Since you are using `$('#hdid')` to search the element, you always get the first.

Answer (score 0):

`id=""` should be unique, if you want more then one element to be `hdid` use the `class` attribute. it is this that is causing your problem. so 'fix' the html to be like

```
<div class="delete">ABC<input type="text" name="hdid1" class="hdid" />
```

and the js like

```
$(function() {             
    $(".delete").click(function() {                 
        var hidden = $(this).children('input.hdid').val();                 
        console.log(hidden);                 
        console.log(this);             
    });         
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you have multiple elements with the same ID. This isn't really allowed, and so when asked for the value of the element with an ID of "hdid", jQuery will just take the  value of the first one it finds.

One possible solution here is to have just one hidden input field, and update the value of this when a particular item is clicked on, then submit the form. You could store the IDs of the items you want to delete using a `data-*` attribute (assuming you're using HTML 5):

```
<form id="frmDelete" method="post" action="delete-class.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdid" id="hdid" />
    <ul id="class">
        <li>
            <div class="delete" data-id="6">ED 123-123</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="delete" data-id="7">EDU 121-101</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="delete" data-id="8">STU 120-456</div>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function() {
            $('#hdid').val($(this).data('id'));
            var hidden = $('#hdid').val();
            console.log(hidden);
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```